# How to do fetch and rebase?

Tags: git, rebase

[`git pull` is](https://www.atlassian.com/git/tutorials/syncing/git-pull) just a:

> The `git pull` command is actually a combination of two other commands, `git fetch` followed by `git merge`.

So I can manually do two commands:

```
# I'm on master branch now!

$ git fetch origin master

remote: Enumerating objects: 9, done.
remote: Counting objects: 100% (9/9), done.
remote: Compressing objects: 100% (1/1), done.
remote: Total 5 (delta 4), reused 4 (delta 4), pack-reused 0
Unpacking objects: 100% (5/5), done.
From github.com:user/app
 * branch            master     -> FETCH_HEAD
   2b73030..58a1447  master     -> origin/master

$ git merge origin/master  // <= from 'origin/master'
```

As you can see, in a second command I merge `origin/master` into `master`.

But how to do it with `rebase`? I'm in doubt if `origin/master` is correct for `rebase`:

```
$ git fetch origin master
$ get rebase origin/master // <= is this correct? What is correct way?
```

Comment: `git fetch origin master && git rebase FETCH_HEAD` is more reliable. In some situations `origin/master` does not exist or does not get updated.

Comment: @Green Is the `get` instead of `git` in the last line a typo? (I cannot change it directly because of the six characters rule.)

Answer (score 3):

Yes, that's exactly correct (though I'd simply `git fetch` or `git fetch origin` to have all of your local `origin` mirror updated, which also prevents issues with fairly old versions of Git).

However, you can also simply do `git pull --rebase`.

Comment: I know the command `git pull --rebase`. I want to know how to perform `git pull` with two commands, but the second command is not `merge` but `rebase`.

Comment: @Green well, then it's a good thing I answered that question, too, isn't it? :)